# determine the owner of the windows copy of a PC

Tags: windows-8.1, product-key

Our team have several of Computers. and 3 product keys of windows 8.1 of that PC belongs to me. but i can't remember which machine I put them. how can i find the machine which my product key installed. (I have fully access to them)

Comment: There are dozens of tools that will provide you the Windows key currently installed on a computer.  I would use one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slmgr /dlv` to display **d**etailed **l**icense information.

Comment: thanks. I could have an idea from the partial product key. but that part always unique?